# Updating multiple values in a scroller with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scroller in my page containing 10 static tables which I scroll using jquery-als anylistscroller. The problem is that my data source contains many objects so when I update the tables the only result I get is the last 10 elements from the data source. I tried using setTimeout function to delay the update of values but that didnt work and I could not add tables dynamically to the page.

here is example of the tables

```
<div id="lista2" class="als-container">
<div class="als-viewport">
    <div class="als-wrapper">
        <div class="als-item">
            <table id="table" border="1">
                <tr class="cla">
                    <th rowspan="2" id="01">
                        <img title="img1" id="img01" height="30" width="30" src="~/Images/orderedList0.png">
                    </th>
                    <th id="111">qte
                    </th>
                    <th id="112">var
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="121">prix
                    </td>
                    <td id="122">symb
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    </div>
```

here where I update the values :

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: '@Url.Action("getTickerObjects", "Home")',
    success: function (ListTicker)
    {
            for (var i = 0; i < ListTicker.ListTicker.length; i++)
            {
                var obj = ListTicker.ListTicker[i];
                Update(c, obj.QteE.toString(), obj.Trade_Price.toString(), obj.Price_Trade_Variation.toString(), obj.Mnemonic.toString().trim());
}
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

    }
  });
```

Is there a way I can slow down the updating process ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the defered attribute on an `<script>` tag that points to an external file. Try placing it before the closing `</body>` tag. Here' an [article](http://davidwalsh.name/script-defer)

```
  <script src="script.js" defer="defer"></script>
```